# Network Bandwidth Utilization with SNMP

Tags: snmp

I have configured the bandwidth Utilization with the below formula, data i am getting after snmpwalk.

Utilization = ( ifinOctect * 8 * 100 ) /( ifspeed * delta_time )

now i want to know if what is the unit of output of this command.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

[RFC2863](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2863) defines IF-MIB and has a clear explanation on what `ifInOctets` and `ifSpeed` (paragraph 3.1.7) is:

```
ifInOctets OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Counter32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
            "The total number of octets received on the interface,
            including framing characters. [...]"
```

I would however not use `ifInOctets` on modern devices. Since these are 32-bits counters you're running a high risk of a counter wrap (reaching max-int) before you've read it. When available (and any modern device should have it) `ifHCInOctets` is of more use since it uses a 64-bit counter:

```
ifHCInOctets OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Counter64
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
            "The total number of octets received on the interface,
            including framing characters.  This object is a 64-bit
            version of ifInOctets.
```

Looking at your calculation:

Your calculation seems to be an attempt to determine the link utilisation as a percentage. However, the way you describe it does not work. `ifInOctets` is an absolute number for the total of octets which were received. There's no notion of time there.

To determine link utilisation you would have to take two measurements (the increase in received packets). By dividing that by the time difference `delta_time` you get the average number of packets/sec in the measured time interval. Multiply that by 8 to convert octets into bits. If you divide that result by the `ifSpeed` (which is in bits/sec) you get a fraction representing the interface utilisation. Finally multiplying it by 100 would give you a percentage.

So if `ifInOctet1` and `ifInOctet2` are two consecutive measurements `time_delta` apart in time, the calculation would be:
`Utilization = ((ifInOctet2 - ifInOctet1) * 8 / delta_time) / ifSpeed * 100`

Comment: We are collecting the data every 5 minute, so delta_time is 300.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: i have a silly question when i ran these commands i gets IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.1,IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2, what does these number 1,2 represent here.

Comment: This is SNMP basics, it's a reference to the interface table in which all interfaces are listed.